# SharePoint 2013 - Multiple domains in People picker

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

We have a farm that's setup on Domain A and it has trust to Domain B. By default we can find the users for Domain A in the People Picker, but we would like to add the users for Domain B as well in the People Picker.

I have followed these articles to try and make this happen, without success:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075(v=office.15).aspx
http://www.sharepointdoug.com/2014/06/how-to-configure-people-picker-in.html

I have tried these PowerShell commands:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:DomainA.com; domain:DomainA.com,DomainA\UserA,Pass123;domain:DomainB.com,DomainB\UserB,Pass123" -url "http://TheSite"

stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:DomainA.com,DomainA\UserA,Pass123;domain:DomainB.com,DomainB\UserB,Pass123" -url "http://TheSite"
```

When I run these commands I'm only able to see the users from Domain B in the people picker, but I would like to see both users from Domain A and Domain B.

When I run the following PowerShell command everything goes back to default and I can see users from Domain A only:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "" -url "http://TheSite"
```

I have spent quite a lot of time on this and I'm clearly missing something. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below command. This command worked for us:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:DomainA.com;forest:DomainB.com,DomainB\login,password" -url "Your webapp url"
```

Answer (score 8):

One alternative to using stsadm.exe, as it is a deprecated tool, would instead to use PowerShell. You will also have a bit more control as there are other parameters in PowerShell that cannot be set through stsadm.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$adsearchobj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$adsearchobj.DomainName = "contoso.com"
$adsearchobj.ShortDomainName = "CONTOSO" #Optional
$adsearchobj.IsForest = $true #$true for Forest, $false for Domain

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)
$wa.Update()
```

More details from [PowerShell for People Picker](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/01/powershell-for-people-picker-properties/), including other examples.

Comment: Hi Trevor , I tried script you posted but its not working. we have one way trust between domain where SharePoint servers are and users domain. Do in need account ?

Comment: Yes you must provide an account.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Does this account has to be in domain ? if yes then which one ? Do it need any kind of permission ?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Will this PS command work when the farm is built in Domain A (WFE/APP/DB Servers, Service Accounts, Etc.) and has a one-way Trust to Domain B or will this cause issues when users in Domain B try to access the farm?  This would be very useful instead of migrating the farm to Domain B as I have seen recommended in other info? I can post as new question if you like just let me know

Comment: @Ronak the account needs to be in the untrusting forest (so if DOMB contains SharePoint and trusts DOMA, but DOMA doesn't trust DOMB, the account must be in DOMA).

Comment: @ShaneGib. yes this process is used to allow such trusts configurations to function correctly with the People Picker.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Thanks a bunch, we have a UAT I will give it a try, thanks again for your quick response!

SG.