# Connect SharePoint 2010 to another forest DC

Tags: 2010

I have SharePoint 2010 and Active Directory as a Domain Controller. Now, there is a request from a client who has his own DC and wants to connect to my SharePoint site. 
Note that there is a two-way trust relationship between the 2 DCs.
What are the steps to give them access by using their usernames+pswd?

I tried to create a sync connection through Central Admin by using a username+password that the client gave me but I get an error: The LDAP server is unavailable.

Pls advice!

Comment: Please check below link might be it helpful. https://blog.ed.gs/2014/02/24/two-way-active-directory-cross-domain-trust/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a two-way trust as it is described in the link you provided. What exactly do I have to do next SharePoint-wise?

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

If two way trust is already set. Then you can run below `stsadm` commands from your server:

**Step 1:**

First, you have to set an encryption key on all web servers in your farm so that the stored credentials can be encrypted:

Just to be clear, you have to run this on all web servers in your farm and the "AnyKey" value has to be set to the same value on all of those servers.

```
STSADM.exe -o setapppassword -password AnyKey
```

where "AnyKey" is any value. For example,

```
STSADM.exe -o setapppassword -password B1gL0ngPassw0rd
```

**Step 2**

Next, you have to run below stsadm command to search users from other domain in people picker  and give them access

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:DomainA.com;forest:DomainB.com,DomainB\login,password" -url "Your webapp url"
```

I have done this and it worked for us

Reference: [SharePoint 2013 - Multiple domains in People picker](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/sharepoint-2013-multiple-domains-in-people-picker/174397)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I run the command but i get the answer: "Cannot retrieve the information for application credential key"

Comment: Hi Maria, Please check below link for error you mentioned http://www.sharepointlovers.com/error-cannot-retrieve-the-information-for-application-credential-key/

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check now.